# Div click and hover effect parent to child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 3 parent div's and and 3 child div's . when i clicked on parent div equivalent child div should visible.both parent and child equivalent list. 
whenever user hover the 1'st div ul li equivalent child ul li add some class(highlight). and at a time second div's also work like that.not effect to one div to another. 
i wrote some code here it's some part working fine. i want optimize code . is there any may apply oops for this code.

and some is buggy . is there any way to do this with out using getting index number

HTML CODE

```
 <div class="myparent">
                        <div class="parent">
                            <ul>
                                <li>test1</li>
                                <li>test2</li>
                                <li>test3</li>
                            </ul>

                            click here and hover and test-'s
                        </div>
                        <div class="parent">
                            <ul>
                                <li>test1</li>
                                <li>test2</li>
                                <li>test3</li>
                            </ul>
    click here and hover and test-'s
                        </div>

                        <div class="parent"></div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="mychaild">
                        <div class="chaild" style="display:none">
                            <ul>
                                 <li>test1</li>
                                <li>test2</li>
                                <li>test3</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="chaild" style="display:none">
                            <ul>
                                <li>test1</li>
                                <li>test2</li>
                                <li>test3</li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="chaild" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        indexn = $('.parent').index(this);
        $('.chaild:eq(' + indexn + ')').show();
        $('.parent:eq(' + indexn + ') ul li').hover(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            chaildindex = $('.parent:eq(' + indexn + ') ul li').index(this);
            $('.chaild:eq(' + indexn + ') ul li:eq(' + chaildindex + ')').toggleClass('selected');
        });
    });
});
```

FOR MORE UNDERSTANDING  http://codepen.io/sarath704/pen/cpKsJ

or  http://jsbin.com/Aqidopi/1/edit

AND give me suggestions i am  new to JavaScript and jQuery programming

Comment: I don't quite understand your question - do you mean that when you hover over the parent's "test" children, the children in the corresponding div should also be highlighted, but you have problem achieving that effect? Also, your HTML is invalid in a sense that the direct descendant of a `<ul>` element can only be `<li>`. If you want to nest a `<ul>` within another, you will have to nest it inside a `<li>` first.

Comment: when click on parent div should visible child div. parent div's  test's hover should highlight child  div test's (add class).problem with getting effect also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is to bind the `.hover()` function outside of the click event, not inside it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        indexn = $('.parent').index(this);
        $('.chaild:eq(' + indexn + ')').show();
    });
    $('.parent ul li').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        var liIndex = $(this).index(),
            parentIndex = $(this).parents('.parent').index();
        $('.chaild:eq('+parentIndex+') > ul > li:eq('+liIndex+')').toggleClass('selected');
    });

});
```

http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/qzlfh

Comment: thanks it's works for me . but i want some additional. that hover if i click . in chaild nested ul  should be visible. (menusel). and please tell me is any way to write this code with out indexes using jquery predifined methods.

Comment: What I would suggest is actually to clone the parent, so that you will have same menu layouts.

Comment: structure is same but there is lot of different in internal implementation